# CSV File to Salesforce records

Tags: web-services, base64, salesforce, apex

I have a custom object Employee with fields below. The employee data is maintained in an external system which is sending a base64 encoded string of the csv extract by calling a web service.

I am able to decode the string by using EncodingUtil.base64Decode(). My question is how can I prepare inserts from the decoded base64 string in Salesforce custom object.

[image]

```
String File = 'U25vLE5hbWUsTGFzdCBOYW1lLEVtcCBJZCxKb2IgRnVuY3Rpb24NCjEsU2FjaGluLENob3VyYXNpeWEsMzMwLEJ1c2luZXNzDQoyLFJhamF0ICxTYXhlbmEgLDMzNCxGdW5jdGlvbmFsDQo=';
String myFile = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(file).toString();
System.debug('Sachin'+'['+ myFile + ']');
```

Debug logs
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer by myself. Please take a look and provide feedback.

```
String File = 'U25vLE5hbWUsTGFzdCBOYW1lLEVtcCBJZCxKb2IgRnVuY3Rpb24NCjEsU2FjaGluLENob3VyYXNpeWEsMzMwLEJ1c2luZXNzDQoyLFJhamF0ICxTYXhlbmEgLDMzNCxGdW5jdGlvbmFsDQo=';
String myFile = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(file).toString();
System.debug('Sachin'+'['+ myFile + ']');
List<String> EmployeeList = new List<String>();
EmployeeList = myFile.split('\n');

List<Employee__c> employeeInsertList = new List<Employee__c>();

for (String employee : EmployeeList)
{
    List<String> fields = new List<String>();
    fields = employee.split(',');
    Employee__c empRecord = new Employee__c();

    empRecord.LastName__c = fields[2];
    empRecord.Name = fields[1];
    empRecord.EmpId__c = fields[3];
    empRecord.Job_Function__c = fields[4];
    employeeInsertList.add(empRecord); 

}
System.debug('Employee List is '+employeeInsertList);
insert employeeInsertList;
```